# Sveltekit Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, svelte, firebase-hosting, svelte-3, sveltekit

How can I use SvelteKit and firebase hosting? firebase hosting requires the html file to be called Index.html while SvelteKit calls it app.html. I think it has something to do with SvelteKit adaptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [configure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) Firebase to serve the file you want.

```json
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Serves app.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/app.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me for some reason :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you must use SSG (Static site generation) since Firebase Hosting is for static websites.

Official sveltekit SSG docs https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static,

When you render your website, you will get a build folder where all the html files are prerendered.

On the docs you will see detailed instructions on how to configure the adapter but here is a short version.

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

and of course, you have to

```
npm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-static
```