# How to configure firebase.json to serve Sveltes app.html instead of index.html

Tags: firebase, svelte, firebase-hosting, sveltekit

I tried to rewrite the destination from index.html to app.html like in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70761896/10763336) but somehow it's not working. In the picture below is my directory structure. Maybe I am using a wrong path and cant see it.

[image]

The contents of my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "src",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/app.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `"public": "src"` in your `firebase.json`? Firebase should server `index.html` present in the directory that you specify.

Comment: Yes, public is set to "src". I'm going to make an Edit and add the contents of my firebase.json.

Comment: Why do you want to deploy the src folder and not the build?

Comment: @Corrl I realized that this is, in fact, not the problem I'm facing. The problem is that *npm run build* is not building into my *public* folder but into the *svelte.kit* folder.

Comment: So the question changed? Or is it solved?

Comment: Well now I have a different problem. But I think I can figure it out. Once it is working, I'm going to update the question with the Solution.